# Android Java draw to canvas each millisecond

Tags: java, android, multithreading, canvas

I want to draw in some Activity. I've used threads with SurfaceViews, but it doesn't push changes at all! Here you can see my previous things:

```
            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (canvas) {
                    this.gameSurface.update();
                    this.gameSurface.draw(canvas);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Do nothing.
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                    this.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
            try {
                sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

(Thread handling example - I've checked, it'd drown only first time, but then it had not pushed any changes). So, should I change `SurfaceView` to something else, or this is a good solution and I have to find errors?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to stay on clear android engine. I've fixed all my problems with canvas redrowing. If anyone have some issues: just push changes inside SurfaceView to itself, just like this:

```
public void update() {
        invalidate();
        Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas(null);
        this.draw(canvas);
        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```